# How to loop an encrypted data bag in chef

Tags: chef-infra

I have an encrypted databag that contain multiple elements.How to loop through all the elements in the encrypted data bag.

Below is the code that i tried in my recipie, but the loop always return encrypted values.

```
db_details = data_bag_item("data-bag-item", "data_bag_id",IO.read("# {node['secret-file']}"))

<% @db_details.each_pair do |key, value| %>
<%= "INSERT INTO data (key, value) VALUES 
('#{key}', '#{value}';" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: A code snippet would go a long way here.

Comment: Added the code snippet that i have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data bag items support most methods from Ruby's Hash class.So at first instance it looks that we can just loop through the hash.

```
db_details = data_bag_item("data-bag-item", "data_bag_id",IO.read("#   {node['secret-file']}"))

<% @db_details.each_pair do |key, value| %>
<%= "INSERT INTO data (key, value) VALUES 
('#{key}', '#{value}';" %>
<% end %>
```

But EncryptedDataBagItem represents a read-only data bag item where all values, except for the value associated with the id key, have been encrypted.So it cannot be iterated like a normal ruby hash.EncryptedDataBagItem class expose a method called #to hash that gives a decrypted data bag.Use this method to loop through the data bag item

```
<% @db_details.to_hash.each_pair do |key, value| %>
<%= "INSERT INTO data (key, value) VALUES 
('#{key}', '#{value}';" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `to_hash`.

```
db_details = data_bag_item("data-bag-item", "data_bag_id",IO.read("# {node['secret-file']}"))
db_details_iterable = db_details.to_hash
db_details_iterable.each do |k, v|
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Data bag items support most methods from Ruby's `Hash` class. See [the `Hash#each` documentation for details](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-each).

Comment: Hash#each gives back encrypted data, where as the requirement is to get decrypted data.